# pyspark: How to fill values in a column and replace with column from another dataframe with conditions

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

I have two dataframes. One raw (40 columns) and another transformed (60 columns)
For the ease of understanding, I have mentioned only 3 columns for example.

df1_raw with 40 columns

```
ID     city      State
2      Montreal  Quebec
3      Airdrie   Alberta
4      Edmonton  Alberta
5      Leduc     Alberta
6      Brandon   Manitoba
7      Winnipeg  Manitoba
9      St. John  Newfoundland
```

df_transformed with 60 columns

```
ID     city      State    
2      Montreal  Quebec
3                Alberta
4      Edmonton  Alberta
5                Alberta
6      Brandon   Manitoba
7                Manitoba
9      St. John  Newfoundland
```

If the 'city' column is null in the df_transformed, then I need to fetch 'city' from df1_raw with join on "ID"

Hence, the results will be like

```
 3      Airdrie   Alberta ....
```

If I have to use coalesce, then there are huge number of columns that needs to renamed and dropped later after join. Is there a way to achieve this? Thanks.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this work? You only have to rename the `city` column once at the end.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import coalesce

df_transformed.join(df1_raw.select('ID', 'city'), ['ID'], "left")\
                .withColumn('new_city', coalesce(df_transformed.city, df1_raw.city))\
                .drop('city').withColumnRenamed('new_city', 'city').show()

+---+------------+--------+
| ID|       State|    city|
+---+------------+--------+
|  2|      Quebec|Montreal|
|  3|     Alberta| Airdrie|
|  4|     Alberta|Edmonton|
|  5|     Alberta|   Leduc|
|  6|    Manitoba| Brandon|
|  7|    Manitoba|Winnipeg|
|  9|Newfoundland|St. John|
+---+------------+--------+
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your solution. As I have like 40 columns in the raw and 60 columns in the df_transformed, When I join both,  I get around 100 columns and hence dropping 40 columns seems bit tedious actually. Hence I am looking for any other options.

Comment: Alright, how about replacing `drop('State')` with `select('ID', 'city')`? Now you don't have to drop any columns from `df1_raw`. (Edited my code)

Comment: Yes, thanks. In order to by pass many columns from df_raw, I just created, a df_temp('ID', 'city') and joined that with df_transformed and after coalace, dropped the necessary columns. Thanks for the suggestions.